# Opening the connection to OLEDB terminates the code

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, oledb, dbase

I am trying to create a dbf file in C#. Somehow when I am trying to open the connection to OLEDB, the program terminates without throwing an exception. Below is the code:

```
private void CreateDBFFile()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dBaseConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + @" Data Source=k:\Temp; " + @"Extended Properties=dBase IV"))
            {
                dBaseConnection.Open();

                string createTableSyntax =
                    "Create Table Person " +
                    "(Name char(50), City char(50), Phone char(20), Zip decimal(5))";
                var cmd = new OleDbCommand(createTableSyntax, dBaseConnection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string x = ex.Message;

        }

    }
```

The error is thrown right here:

```
dBaseConnection.Open();
```

I checked the event logs and that does not help either. Below is the error log from event log:'

```
Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe, version: 10.0.14358.1000, time 
stamp: 0x574fc56b
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1649.1, time stamp: 0x58f97fe6
 Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0045068d
 Faulting process id: 0x3354
 Faulting application start time: 0x01d2eeacd40d1e91
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
 Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
 Report Id: 18960866-5aa0-11e7-b3f6-005056c00008
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get the exception and look at it's Message property (the contents of string `x`) for better error info. You're already getting the string... it will be useful to actually look at what it says.

Comment: I would have get the exception if the code was throwing an exception. The code just terminates without throwing an exception at line : dbconnection.open()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have your connection is not ideal.

Do this instead then step through the code and you should be able to get an exception or it would work: 
Put your connection string inside web.config.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connection" connectionString="Data Source=k:\Temp; xtended Properties=dBase IV Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" />    
  </connectionStrings>


string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
           using (OleDbConnection dBaseConnection = new OleDbConnection(connection))
           {
               if (dBaseConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
               {
                   dBaseConnection.Open();
               }
           }
```

Comment: I am putting connection string in web.config file. In order to show my entire code, I put the connection string in the using statement, Also, putting connection string in web.config file will not change the code. It will be just reading the connection string from config file rather than the code itself. It is still terminating the code when I am trying to open the connection.

Comment: Yes i understand it wont change. Just that its cleaner, but i get why you put it just to show entire code. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I removed this line from my connection string

```
     "Extended Properties=dBase IV ".
```

The code started working.